# Tabcontroller problem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can i rotate tabbarcontroller in landscape mode  when i am having XIB file(tab bar controller) in portait.i wrote the follwing in appdelegate

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  return YES;
  }
  , but it wont be rotated any help please?

Answer (score 0):

AS i remember, you cannot rotate the SDK's UITabBar controller. You chold make your own tabbar, inherint it from UITabBar and there return YES in shouldAutoRotate method.

> ```
> #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>    
>   @interface MainTabBarController : UITabBarController{
>   }    
>  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;
> @end
> ```

this is an .h file

> ```
> #import "MainTabBarController.h"
> @implementation MainTabBarController
> - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
> {
>     return YES;
> } 
> @end
> ```

You just have to change class of your tabbar from UITabBarController to MainTabBarController

Comment: Oh, i have no mac with XCode right now nerby. You can try to inherit your own TabBar from UITabBar (in your .h file @interface MyTabBar : UITabBar). You can implement noting exept your shouldAutorotate... method in .m file. Correct example I can post only on monday.

Comment: Ok, I'll post an example in a few hours.